# css - removing background image

Tags: css

i have this image in the background:

http://yoursdproperty.com/templates/pjo_joomlaforall/images/bgr.png

of this page:

http://yoursdproperty.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&fileid=8&Itemid=34

how do i remove it?

i understand that if i remove it the page will just be white in the background correct? if not, what do i need to do to get rid of the gray and white and just make it white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the following style you should get what you want:

```
#background_right {
/*background:transparent url(../images/bgr.png) no-repeat fixed center top;*/
background-color:white;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: nope it doesnt work, try it yourself, you will see that there is still a gray background

Comment: Are you still having the problem? or is it fixed now?

Comment: Also if you mean that you have just made the change on the site link you passed through, I have just checked and it shows that you have not made the change. If you think that you have made it, it could be that a proxy is caching the CSS somewhere.

Comment: perhaps you can also answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173547/css-increasing-size-of-holder-or-what-ever-its-called

Answer (score 2):

*Just* remove or outcomment the particular CSS line responsible for this. Or am I thinking too simple about this problem? If so, then please elaborate more about the context of the problem. If it is for instance an autogenerated stylesheet which you don't have control over, then best what you can do is to grab JavaScript ([jQuery](http://jquery.com)?) to remove/override the background image in the particular style class.

**Edit**: if you rather want a *white* background, then you'll need to get rid of the `.body_background` class as well.

Comment: perhaps you can also answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173547/css-increasing-size-of-holder-or-what-ever-its-called

Comment: I edited my answer after seeing your complaint "it has still gray background".